# Is it bad practice to pass data to seeder classes from controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I have seeder having these columns

```
public function run($name)
    {
        
        //
        DB::table('cloth')->insert([
            'cloth_start'=>'160',  'cloth_end'=>'172', 'chair_id'=>$name
        ]);
}
```

Its working as i want it to work, I was wondering whether it is a bad practice or not

Comment: Probably not advisable. What are you trying to achieve here, creation of a new record with some default values?

Comment: I have 100 of products and If someone runs my app for first time and populate the database they cant enter the value for chair_id column by default and hence when retrieveing records for a specific product they will get null
Short story i pass id of that chair to this other table seeder so that relationship is maintained
I just want to know if it is a good or a bad practice

Comment: @MohammadFahadRao in your scenario, inside the seed, loop over all the current products stored in your table, and for each of them create some random new elements. But if you insist on doing this on specific items, just create the corresponding random elements inside your controller, no need for seeders.

Answer (score 1):

It's "bad" in that it is not Laravel convention to call seeders from Controllers. Additionally, adding a `$name` argument to the seeder's `run` method may cause it not to work if you do `php artisan db:seed` which is how seeders are usually used.

If you want to reuse the logic, you can put it in a PHP trait or a service class, and both your controller and your seeder can use that trait / service class.